# ImageView, How to set image seem at the front of another image?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a problem with images. How can I bring an image in front of another one.
The problem is I create the images in code. So I can not change order in Layout.

Comment: You can use frame layout for this. 2nd image will be shown on top of 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ImageView.bringToFront();`, maybe is the best solution.

Here's the [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront%28%29)

Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout:

```
RelativeLayout rv = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_ph);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
ImageButton im1 = new ImageButton(this);

im1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lamp);
im1.setId(i);
im1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tx.setText("lamp #" + v.getId());
 }
 });

params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
params.leftMargin = x;
params.topMargin = y;
rv.addView(im1, params);
```

XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/my_ph"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="bottom">
   <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/map" />
   <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
 </TextView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating images via code , you could use LayoutParams to give the second image a negative leftMargin.

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imageParams.leftMargin = -20; // change this value 
    imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,image1.getId());
    image2.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
```

This would force the second image on top of the first image. By changing the left margin you could decide on how much you want the second image to move over the first.